# Programmatically change position of UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to create a simple animation on an UIImage that has to start from the position X = 0 and has to end at the position X = device width
I tried to use the following code inside the viewDidLoad method:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
//CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

for(int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
{
    [_camion setFrame:CGRectMake(x, _camion.frame.origin.y, _camion.frame.size.width, _camion.frame.size.height)];
}
```

But the image doesn't move, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For animations there are better methods instead of a for loop

I try to give you an example:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    CGFloat widthView = self.view.frame.size.width;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        _camion.frame = CGRectMake(widthView, _camion.frame.origin.y, _camion.frame.size.width, _camion.frame.size.height);

    }completion:^(BOOL finished){

        NSLog(@"animation done!");
    }];
}
```

With `animateWithDuration` you can set duration, delay and type (in this case UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn) of animation, so you can have more and better control over the end result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfect :)
Just a note, remove the [] from CGRectMake because they're not needed and will give an error

Comment: @aisfdjjif Oh sorry it was a typo.. i edited ;) thanks